# creating an array to match answer records to question records in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

controller:

```
@questions = Question.order("qtype, position")
@answers = Answer.where(user_id = current_user.id)
```

user model:

```
has_many :answers
```

question model:

```
has_many :answers
```

answer model:

```
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

Prior to rails i would have...

1. created an array
2. queried the database to put the questions in it
3. then queried the database to get the answer from the current user for each question and placed it in the array
4. write the view to display the array

I am struggling with how to construct this in rails three. Should i...

- use scope in a model to assemble this?
- write code in the controller to assemble this?
- write the view to render each question with a query to the database to obtain the answer for each question as it is being rendered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a scope or method in the model. A common Rails mantra is "fat models, skinny controllers". In keeping with that phrase, you want to avoid adding all of the lookup logic in your controller. Similarly, you don't want to put the logic in the view. You especially do not want to loop over each question and fire off subsequent answer selects (n+1 problems).

As mentioned above, the best solution would be to keep this logic in the model and join the tables together in either a scope or method. Make sure to use `:include` or a `:joins` to get all the information you need from the models. You want to avoid creating unnecessary `SELECT`s.